# How to learn the maximum number of processes that GNU parallel can run at a time?

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I am trying to find a way on how to know the maximum number of jobs that can run simultaneously on my computer using GNU Parallel. We can define the jobs to spawn by `-j<jobs>` argument. But I am not able to find any way how many I can spawn that start at a time.

In normal computers, if we check the number of cores using `top/htop` then that is the maximum processes that can run simultaneously. But I am trying to run this on a supercomputer that allows multiple nodes.

Comment: Not sure what you are driving at or aiming to achieve here? **GNU Parallel** can start 400 jobs on a 4 core CPU, for example. The limit you are more likely to hit is given by `ulimit -u`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question, it is a Linux question. I suggest to ask it on https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 0):

Why not use let GNU Parallel figure it out by using `-j0`?